# node.js crashing after loop iteration

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox

I'm trying to write a performance tool using `node.js` so I can automate it, and store the results in `MySQL`. The tool is supposed to gather how long took for the browser to load a particular webpage. I'm using HttpWatch to measure the performance, and the result is displayed in seconds. The browser utilized is Firefox.
Below is a piece of script I'm using to run the performance test:

```
var MyUrls = [
    "http://google.com",
    "http://yahoo.com"
    ];    

try {

       var win32ole = require('win32ole');
       var control = win32ole.client.Dispatch('HttpWatch.Controller');
       var plugin = control.Firefox.New();
       for (var i=0; i < MyUrls.length; i++) {
          var url = MyUrls[i];
          console.log(url);
          for(var j=0; j < 14; j++) {
            // Start Recording HTTP traffic
            plugin.Log.EnableFilter(false);
            // Clear Cache and cookier before each test
            plugin.ClearCache();
            plugin.ClearAllCookies();   
            plugin.ClearSessionCookies();
            plugin.Record();
            // Goto to the URL and wait for the page to be loaded
            plugin.GotoURL(url);
            control.Wait(plugin, -1);
            // Stop recording HTTP
            plugin.Stop();
            if ( plugin.Log.Pages.Count != 0 )
            {           
               // Display summary statistics for page
               var summary = plugin.Log.Pages(0).Entries.Summary;
               console.log(summary.Time);
            }
          }
       }
       plugin.CloseBrowser();
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('*** exception cached ***\n' + e);
    }
```

After the second iteration of the inner loop, I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\test\browser-perf>node FF-load-navigation.js
http://localhost/NFC-performance/Bing.htm
[Number (VT_R8 or VT_I8 bug?)]
2.718
[Number (VT_R8 or VT_I8 bug?)]
2.718
OLE error: [EnableFilter] -2147352570 [EnableFilter] IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames Au
toWrap() failed
```

Have someone seen this before? Can you help me?

Comment: Where are the API docs for the Firefox "plugin" you are using? I have doubts that the methods like `ClearCache` and `ClearCookies` are synchronous (i.e. blocking execution until operation has complete). If instead they are asynchronous, you need to specify callbacks for them. https://github.com/idobatter/node-win32ole says "Asynchronous, non-blocking win32ole bindings" - what I expected.

Comment: It's really weird, the readme of win32ole says that it supposed to be non-blocking, but the examples show all kinds of functions just in a synchronous fashion. It's as if the readme is lying straight in your face.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to remember that node is asynchronous**

So that for loop runs simultaneously to `plugin.CloseBrowser();`, which is obviously not what you want because thats causing it to close, which will cause problems in the for loop.

rather you want that to run *after* the for loop finishes.

Look at [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) for a simple way to do this.

```
async.each(MyUrls, function (callback) {
    ...
    callback()
}, function(err){
    plugin.CloseBrowser();
});
```

The same has to be done for your inner for loop.

Comment: Could you give me more details of your idea Niall?

Comment: @philippe Sure. So node works asynchronously. So if I have say a for loop like you have above, and then some code afterwards, node will run the for loop and at the same time, run the next bit of code. In your code, it runs the for loop, then simultaneously calls `plugin.CloseBrowser();` and considering that you use the `plugin` var in your loop, I'm presuming that calling the function above is going to cause problems. Get me?